# Validate email on enter

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to validate an email textbox when I push the enter button. One problem: when i push enter, the text dissapears and nothing happens.

My code:

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
        mailcontrole();
    }
});

function mailcontrole {

    var mail = $("#email").val();
    if (IsEmail(mail) == false) {
        alert("false");
    }
}

function IsEmail(email) {
    var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-\+])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
    if (!regex.test(email)) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Add a jsfiddle. also try http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the default behaviour of submitting your form using the `ENTER`.

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (e.which == 13) {
        mailcontrole();
    }
});
```

Adding `e.preventDefault();` stops this behaviour!

**UPDATE**

Your function is missing `()` also ( Thanks to Alex )!

```
function mailcontrole() {
    var mail = $("#email").val();
    if (IsEmail(mail) == false) {
        alert("false");
    }
}
```

Comment: Also don't forget to mention that `mailcontrole` function has syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

the form may submit because the form gets submitted when you click enter and that would empty the form.
use [event.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) to make it not submit.

try this:

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
        e.preventDefault();
        mailcontrole();
    }
});
```